# tags of an html page

Tags: java, browser

I want to get all the tags of a html page . I parsed html page and create document(DOM) . But I could not find any method to access all the tags of DOM model.  I am using java .

Comment: What do you mean by "all the tags" - all the tags used on a specific page, or all tags that exist?

Comment: Why didn't you learn to accept answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you parsed your DOM object you can simply iterate all nodes. Otherwise you could try an xpath expression, like `//*`.

Quick sample to get you going

```
public void recurseNodes(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
        Node childNode = nodeList.item(i);
        // do something with the node .. then recurse into childnode
        recurseNodes(childNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean getting all the tags in the DOM using javascript, I would recommend using JQuery as you can simply loop over the document like so

$(document).each(function() {
   $(this)..........
});

Is this what you are looking for?